# Using Policy Authorisation with a MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc

Looking to implement Policies into my Web Application, As some users may have certain claims. For example a role of a user will be the same however different claims.

**User 1**

- Role = "Support"
- Claims = "AddSupport,DeleteSupport"

**User 2**

- Role = "Support"
- Claims = "AddSupport"

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

        ConfigureAuth(app);
        ConfigureServices(services);


    }
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("DeleteSupport", policy => policy.RequireClaim("DeleteSupport"));
        });
    }
```

**Controller**

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize(Policy = "DeleteSupport")]
public class SupportController : Controller
{
```

However the user that doesn't have the claim "DeleteSupport" can still access the SupportController. My current setup is running OWIN if that could cause issues. The solution runs with no errors and is it possible to debug the policy?

**Update**
Tried adding an filter to `AddMvc()`

```
var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
```

Comment: Your `ConfigureServices` adds a Policy for `AddSupport`, but not one for `DeleteSupport`

Comment: @StephenMuecke oops, wrote it out wrong.